# Restriction on Commenting

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

Why is there a 50+ reputation requirement for commenting on someone's question. I use Stack Overflow a lot both at work and at home, but rarely need to ask my own question since there are so many pre-existing. I also don't have much time to answer questions, but I try to when I can.

The problem I find is while I'm under 50 rep I can't comment to clarify what someone is asking, so I can't answer, so I can't earn the last little bit of rep... and the cycle continues.

It just seems overly restrictive to new users.

Comment: I agree with you completely, although we've talked about this extensively on Meta and it seems that most everyone wants to keep the restriction despite the fact that we already use rate limiting to prevent people from spamming with comments... in any case, I upvoted a good answer of yours and you should have enough rep now.

Comment: @eddie_cat I'd be less worried about rate limiting, and more worried about having *that many* more junk comments to clean up. At least at 50 rep a user should have *some* idea of what they are there for (as evidenced by the current lack of abuse, and massive abuse of new "answers" by low rep users).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I understand where you're coming from, but I think it would balance out, since we already have a lot of non-answers to clean up that wouldn't exist if everyone could just comment. ("Did anyone figure this out yet?" "Could you please clarify what MyClass is for?" etc) I'd rather have more junk comments than all these non-answers, which are also very frustrating for people who are trying to contribute in a totally valid way but can't because they are prohibited from doing so.

Comment: Remember edits net you +2 rep, and there are questions that can be answered without commenting.

Comment: Yeah, but the whole reason you're saying allowing everyone to comment is bad is because these people supposedly don't have enough experience with the site to know how to do it right. How are they supposed to know about editing and how to make a *good* edit if they can't even be trusted to make comments?